# How to use parameter fields in Room @Query?

Tags: android, android-room

I have a `User` class with a field `id`, so I wanted to run the following query with Room:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ticket where user_id = :user.id")
LiveData<Ticket> loadFromUser(User user);
```

But I am getting error marks on Android Studio on `user.id` and all examples I find online only use the direct parameter of the `@Query` method, usually a `String` or an `int`.

Is it possible to use an object's field in a Room `@Query`? If positive, so what's the proper way of referencing it.

Comment: This would be a much needed feature, especially in the case you need to use a high number of members of a class.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't pass parameters like that to room. It does not support a full expression language. You have to use primitive types to pass parameters. Like this,

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ticket where user_id = :user_id")
LiveData<Ticket> loadFromUser(String user_id);
```

Comment: So sad that there is no such support :(

Comment: I find room very confining.  I find it almost easier to store the Json query and then just parse that later instead of using room.

Comment: You may add custom method with object parameter as follows:

`default LiveData<Ticket> loadFromUser(User user){ return loadFromUser(user.id); }`

Comment: String is not primitive type!

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution is to create two other functions, one is for `user_id` and one is for `user` as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ticket where user_id = :user_id")
LiveData<Ticket> loadFromUser(String user_id);

@Transaction
LiveData<Ticket> loadFromUser(User user){
   return loadFromUser(user.id);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

in my case i used `@RawQuery`

in DAO you can write

```
@RawQuery
LiveData<Ticket> loadFromUser(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

and create your query and pass to it.

```
SimpleSQLiteQuery query  = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM ticket where user_id = ?") , new Object[]{user.id})
```

and pass this `query` to DAO method.

```
userDao.loadFromUser(query)
```

Comment: That's a lot more complicated for no reason, just use the other solution