# Get vararg parameter size in Room Query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Say I have a DB with two main entities (Song and Tag) and a many-to-many relationship between them. Using Room, I want to query the Songs that have a series of Tags (all of them) by their names.

So, given this example data in the cross ref table (SongTagCrossRef):

| Song | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| song1 | tag1 |
| song1 | tag2 |
| song1 | tag3 |
| song2 | tag2 |
| song3 | tag2 |
| song3 | tag3 |

I want the query to return only song1 if I enter tag1 and tag2, as it's the only song related to both.

I've come up with this `@Query` in the corresponding Dao:

```
@Query("""
    SELECT s.* FROM Song s
    JOIN SongTagCrossRef st ON s.song_id = st.song_id
    JOIN Tag t ON st.tag_id = t.tag_id
    WHERE t.name IN (:tagNames)
    GROUP BY s.song_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tag WHERE name IN (:tagNames))
""")
fun getSongsWithAllOfTheTagsByName(vararg tagNames: String): List<SongEntity>
```

Since I can't access `tagNames.size` in the `@Query`, I've had to use a subquery to artificially get it. This subquery shouldn't be too heavy, but it would always be better to somehow access `tagNames.size`.

After reading the answers to a [slightly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851243/how-to-use-parameter-fields-in-room-query), I've been toying with creating a `@RawQuery` and calling it from a function that takes only `tagNames`, something along these lines:

```
@RawQuery
fun getSongsWithAllOfTheTagsByName(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<SongEntity>

fun getSongsWithAllOfTheTagsByName(vararg tagNames: String): List<SongEntity> {
    val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery("""
        SELECT s.* FROM Song s
        JOIN SongTagCrossRef st ON s.song_id = st.song_id
        JOIN Tag t ON st.tag_id = t.tag_id
        WHERE t.name IN (?)
        GROUP BY s.song_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = ?
    """, arrayOf(tagNames, tagNames.size))
    return getSongsWithAllOfTheTagsByName(query)
}
```

*(only converting `tagNames` to something it can actually swallow)*

But I've discarded this approach because I don't want to expose a function that takes a query.

Is there a simpler, more elegant way to write this query?

Comment: I think we can add second optional parameter with default value like `...(vararg tagNames: String, tagNamesCount: Int = tagNames.size)` and use it in query `:tagNamesCount`

Comment: @AkakiKapanadze That's a good suggestion, I hadn't thought about that. There's one drawback, though: the second parameter would be exposed too, so it would be possible to call the function with another Int value and completely break the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it, so I want to share what I found out. It's actually not quite straightforward, but it does the trick.

Going through the SQLite documentation, I came upon the [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) and more specifically the [json_array()](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jarray) and [json_array_length()](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jarraylen) functions.

However, to use this extension, as [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) points out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65267351/6100280) and [Hooman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3211593/hooman) summarises [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67068379/6100280), [Requery's standalone library](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) must be used, through `RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory`.

In conclusion:

build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.requery:sqlite-android:3.36.0'
    ...
}
```

Room database class

```
Room.databaseBuilder(...)
    ...
    .openHelperFactory(RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
    ...
    .build()
```

Dao interface

```
@Query("""
    SELECT s.* FROM Song s
    JOIN SongTagCrossRef st ON s.song_id = st.song_id
    JOIN Tag t ON st.tag_id = t.tag_id
    WHERE t.name IN (:tagNames)
    GROUP BY s.song_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(JSON_ARRAY(:tagNames))
""")
fun getSongsWithAllOfTheTagsByName(vararg tagNames: String): List<SongEntity>
```